PrimeVue styles as "no defined" on Nuxt 3 app
What is happening?
My goal is to register PrimeVue as a module and import PrimeVue components correctly in my layouts with the default preset styles.
Thing is that when I inspect the button in the browser it has the PrimeVue classes but the style variables like colors are not defined.
For example:

--p-button-primary-color is not defined

What have I tried?
Using latest version of everything and followed this guide:
https://primevue.org/nuxt/
My nuxt.config.js looks like this:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  css: ["@/assets/style/app.scss"],
  components: {
    dirs: ["~/components"],
  },
  modules: [
    "@pinia/nuxt",
    "nuxt3-notifications",
    "@nuxt/eslint",
    "dayjs-nuxt",
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
    '@primevue/nuxt-module'
  ],
  primevue: {
    preset: "Aura",
    options: {
      prefix: 'p',
      cssLayer: false
    }
  },
  dayjs: {
    locales: ['es', 'en'],
    plugins: ['relativeTime', 'utc', 'timezone'],
    defaultLocale: 'es',
    defaultTimezone: 'Europe/Madrid',
  },
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
  devtools: { enabled: true },
});

And the component I'm trying to import is this one:
<Button label="Check" icon="pi pi-check" />

Well, you have to install two other libraries

primeicons for showing the icons in the primeVue library
primevue/themes to add themes like Aura in the project (version 4.0.0-rc.2)

after that, I changed my Nuxt.config.ts:
import Aura from '@primevue/themes/aura';
 export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ["@primevue/nuxt-module"],
  primevue: {
    options: {
      theme: {
          preset: Aura,
      },
    }
  },
  css: ["primeicons/primeicons.css"]
});


Thanks! it worked like a charm! Couldn't find a proper guide on how to make it work. I had been working with PrimeVue on several Vue 3 projects (not Nuxt) for more than a year and it was never necessary to install those two libraries there...
